# Jquery + ASP.NET UpdatePanels

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I've been busily implementing JQuery throughout our custom CRM at work. In the process I create a bordered panel, which has the a simple button in it's header which collapses or expands the contents depending on what it's current state is. Now to remember the state of the panel I'm using the jquery cookie library, which when the page is submitted sets a cookie for that control, and then when the page is reloaded it reads and resets the panel to it's last state.

Problem one was getting JQuery to execute on the submit of the page, because ASP.NET takes over this and wouldn't call the submit() functions on the form. To overcome this, I found http://kenbrowning.blogspot.com/2009/01/supporting-jquerys-formsubmit-in-aspnet.html which seemed to work almost flawlessly.

However... After further testing, I've discovered that this will prevent any postbacks that are meant to occur within an UpdatePanel, to do a full Postback, instead of Async one from the panel. I realise UpdatePanels are a little out-dated now, but they are littered throughout our site, so in order to use this control it will have to work nicely with them.

So, is there anyway of determining if an async postback has taken place?? Basically I want to be able to do something like this:

```
if (IsAsyncPostback) {
    theForm.submit(); //this seems to still fire the async postback, but doesn't call the jquery which is setup to save the state..
} else {
    $(theForm).submit(); //this is from the link, which cause all postbacks to be full on postbacks, even if they are in an updatepanel
}
```

Help, I've searched around and haven't been able to find anything useful.. Sure I can't be the only person who has tried this?

Comment: is your problem that you need to run jQuery code each time an UpdatePanel has something to post, or you just want to determine if it's an AsyncPostback ?

Comment: The problem is that when an AsyncPostback is suppose to happen, it doesn't. It does a normal Postback. I need to be able to save the state of the panel whenever a normal postback happens, which is why I was using this method. For Asyncpostback, I can probably get away with not saving the state, as the user doesn't leave the page anyways..

Comment: Are you trying to basically use the [TOGGLE](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) Function?

Comment: Yes I am using the toggle function, and was using this code to save state of toggle in cookie. $(theForm).submit(function() { if($('#panelID').is("":hidden"")) {$.cookie('#panelID', 'True');} else {;$.cookie('#panelID', 'False');} return true;});

Comment: You know about `beginRequest` and `endRequest`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid interfering with the `__doPostBack()` function.

I think what you want is to handle the PageRequestManager's `beginRequest` or `endRequest` events.  This will run your code after every UpdatePanel refresh, for example:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function() {
  if ($('#panelID').is(':hidden'))
    $.cookie('#panelID', 'true');
  else
    $.cookie('#panelID', 'false');
});
```

---

If you really wanted to change `__doPostBack()`, it would be better to do so with this sort of approach:

```
var oldDoPostBack = window.__doPostBack;

window.__doPostBack = function(target, arg) {
  // Trigger a custom event, to track when this occurs.
  $(window).trigger('doPostBack');

  // Call the real __doPostBack() function;
  oldDoPostBack(target, arg);
}
```

Then, you could bind to that custom event to take actions when `__doPostBack()` was triggerd from any source:

```
$(window).bind('doPostBack', function() {
  alert('__doPostBack is about to execute.');
});
```

The important advantage here is that you aren't redefining `__doPostBack()`, so there's less chance that you'll break it.

I'd recommend sticking with the built-in PageRequestManager events though, unless you really do need to catch `__doPostBack()` events for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx ?